# Enabling ringtones in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm brand spanking new to Android. I'm trying to develop an app that mutes the phone depending on the location. I think I got a rudimentary GPS working, but that is not my problem

I'm initiating a voice call to the device (using DDMS in Eclipse), and though it shows that it is ringing, I do not hear any ringtone.

The settings in the emulated device for ringtones only has a ringtone called 'Silent'?? What's wrong?

I just want the phone to ring when it gets a call, but even Google does not seem to have the answer to this simple question.

Please help. Very very confused :-(

(I'm using Eclipse Helios, Android 2.2 and Win7 x64, if that is of any relevance)

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use a real phone instead of the emulator. i do not know if the emulator is able to ring. is it that important? you can see if the phone is muted in the taskbar of course. have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) if you want ringing.